# Calling interactive functions sequentially in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

My init.el is dynamically generated from init.org. I also generate init.html documentation from the init.org file.

I can manually call `M-x org-babel-tangle` and `M-x org-export-as-html` without problem, but I'd like a single function that does both.

I wrote the following function:

```
(defun export-init-org ()
  "Generate init.html and init.html from the current init.org file."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'org-export-as-html)
  (call-interactively 'org-babel-tangle))
```

This doesn't work. It creates the init.html file, but not the init.el file. I tried reordering the calls:

```
(defun export-init-org ()
  "Generate init.html and init.html from the current init.org file."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'org-babel-tangle)
  (call-interactively 'org-export-as-html))
```

This works as expected, both init.el and init.html are created. Why is this? What was wrong with my first function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have `org-export-as-html` in my org installation. I suspect you're using an older version. However, I think what you're seeing is a consequence of the side effects the `org-export-as-html` file. If this function causes Emacs to switch buffers, you'll end up calling `org-babel-tangle` on the html result, and not the org source. This of course does not work. Try this instead to confirm:

```
(defun export-init-org ()
  "Generate init.html and init.html from the current init.org file."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion ;; restores original buffer after running
    (call-interactively 'org-export-as-html))
  (call-interactively 'org-babel-tangle))
```

Comment: I'm using stock org-mode from Emacs 24.3.1, and org-export-as-html is defined in org-html.el. org-version is "7.9.3f". Would you recommend upgrading?

Comment: `save-selected-window` fixes the issue, exactly as described. Thanks! I'm surprised though, because I didn't notice the buffer changing when calling the function.

Comment: The export functionschanged recently, maybe version 8? You don't need to upgrade, but until you do keep this in mind if you encounter issues with exporting.

Comment: You probably want to use `save-excusrion` rather than `save-selected-window` (which does other things on top of preserving the current buffer).

Comment: I'll take your word for it, Stefan! I have a hard time with the docs for save-excursion vs save-current-buffer vs save-selected window etc.